# Excel Pivot Table Count of Sub-Rows

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2016

I have a Pivot Table structure as follows:

ROWS:

```
+-State
+---Customer
+-----Brand
```

Columns:

```
+-Cost
```

***I would like to have another column that contains the number of Customers in each state***. The issue being that my data contains every order that the customers had placed, so when I try to get the count of Customers it is returning every instance of said customer in the column. Another issue is that my data is 40,000 rows, so I want to try and avoid having to edit the raw data.

I can easily do this with brute force, but I was wondering if there is anyway to do this with standard pivot tables and no add-ons. The pivot table already does a nice job of consolidating the unique values for customers, now I just need a count of those unique values.

Comment: You could try putting a manual formula outside the pivot table to just count up what you find in the correct columns.

Comment: Take a look at this method for showing distinct values: http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/distinct-count-in-pivot-tables-finally-in-excel-2013/